# Different query results while using DATE_TRUNC function in WHERE clause

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query which gives different set of result when I use condition

```
DATE_TRUNC('DAY', timestamp) BETWEEN  date_trunc('DAY', NOW()) - interval '14' day AND  date_trunc('DAY', NOW())
```

and a different result when I use condition

```
timestamp BETWEEN  date_trunc('DAY', NOW()) - interval '14' day AND  date_trunc('DAY', NOW())
```

After cross checking both the query results I found that first condition is giving correct result.
Can someone please tell me the difference between both the conditions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And is `timestamp` a timestamp with or without a timezone?

Comment: From function NOW() it seems mysql. Isn't it?

Comment: @GordonLinoff timestamp is the utc timestamp

Comment: @AnkitBajpai yes :)

Answer (score 0):

`timestamp` has a time component.

`date_trunc(day, timestamp)` removes the time component.

The second part of the comparison is different.  The first version returns *any* time on the current day.

The second version only returns midnight on the current day.

Incidentally, I would recommend:

```
where timestamp >= current_date - interval '14 day' and
      timestamp < current_date + interval '1 day'
```

This works, regardless of whether the `timestamp` column has a time component or not.  And, it is friendly to the optimizer and index usage.